# v-bind:style вынести в computed VUE JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

День добрый. 
С помощью  :style забиндила стили внутри Html-кода, теперь понимаю, что логичнее было бы такой кусок кода поместить в computed внутри скрипта. Но не понимаю теперь, как грамотно это сделать.
Помогите пожалуйста. Как свойства из :style грамотно вынести в computed

Comment: `blockStyles() { return { backgroundColor: '... }}`

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    rangeRed: 50,
    rangeGreen: 40,
    rangeBlue: 110,
    rangeAlpha: .5,
    rangeWidth: 100,
    rangeHeight: 200,
    rangeRadius: 10
  },
  computed: {
    blockStyles() {
      return {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba('+ this.rangeRed + ', ' + this.rangeGreen + ', ' + this.rangeBlue + 
                ', ' + this.rangeAlpha  + ')', 
        width: this.rangeWidth + 'px', 
        height: this.rangeHeight + 'px',
        borderRadius: this.rangeRadius + '%'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div :style="blockStyles"></div>
</div>
```